# Parsing intertwined multiline logs with logstash

Tags: multithreading, logstash, multiline

I am trying to parse logs that are of the following form:

```
07/12/16 00:41:03.30 FABsrv.1:fwsrvExecServerRule:FwSelectRawSqlTxn stopped at 00:41:03 , and took 0.000413000
07/12/16 00:41:03.30 FABsrv.1:fwsrvExecServerRule:FwSelectRawSqlTxn started at 00:41:03
07/12/16 00:41:03.30 FABsrv.1:fwsrvExecServerRule:FwSelectRawSqlTxn stopped at 00:41:03 , and took 0.000450000
07/12/16 00:41:03.30 FABsrv.15:FwEventManager:message to process: :>>L FwSrvExecuteRuleTxn msgTag=_INBOX.0A121933.DC05784206C6061BD8.13 ruleName=C2_BATCHCHECK attributes={ { class=ASSOC { class=A1 "PARAMETER" } { class=A1 "VALUE" } } { "USERID" "BC212" } { "EQPID" "FAITU02" } { "LOTIDS" "Q619294" } { "LOTSPPIDS" "Q619294=B401HA/DEFFIN_A" } { "FORCENOMEASURE" "F" } { "FORCEBATCHMAX" "F" } { "TID" "CRO06666_RN004102950_V5.8.0.0004" } }
07/12/16 00:41:03.30 FABsrv.15:fwsrvExecServerRule:FwSelectRawSqlTxn started at 00:41:03
07/12/16 00:41:03.30 FABsrv.1:fwsrvExecServerRule:FwSelectRawSqlTxn started at 00:41:03
07/12/16 00:41:03.30 FABsrv.1:fwsrvExecServerRule:FwSelectRawSqlTxn stopped at 00:41:03 , and took 0.001052000
07/12/16 00:41:03.30 FABsrv.15:fwsrvExecServerRule:FwSelectRawSqlTxn stopped at 00:41:03 , and took 0.001576000
07/12/16 00:41:03.30 FABsrv.15:fwsrvExecServerRule:FwSelectRawSqlTxn started at 00:41:03
07/12/16 00:41:03.31 FABsrv.15:fwsrvExecServerRule:FwSelectRawSqlTxn stopped at 00:41:03 , and took 0.000910000
07/12/16 00:41:03.31 FABsrv.15:C2_BATCHCHECK:CAPITraceDiagnostic - finish executing rule C2_BATCHCHECK:Reply
```

They are generated by a pool of threads running on some server that all write to a single file and I need to extract information from blocks of them keeping in mind the following constraints:

- Events are multiline, those `stopped` and `started` you see can have lines between them and those need to be joined together
- Events are intertwined, the third column specifies which thread wrote which line and each thread needs to correspond to a different stream of data
- I need a thread safe solution

That last point is the real problem, since what is currently in use is the `multiline` filter with its `stream-identity` option to split the stream based on the thread number, but that solution can't scale to the amount of data we have now and the `mutiline` filter is deprecated in favor of`multiline-codec` which is thread safe, but does not support that stream-splitting functionality.

Splitting the logs into mutiple files would be my obvious solution but this is not possible for operational reasons.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You might want to take a look to the [aggregate plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-aggregate.html).

Comment: aggregate isn't thread safe "You should be very careful to set logstash filter workers to 1 (-w 1 flag) for this filter to work correctly otherwise documents may be processed out of sequence and unexpected results will occur."

Comment: If you can accept the performance hit, just run it with one thread

Comment: The actual log throughput is too much for me to keep doing that sadly.

Comment: In that case, a solution is to have more than one instance of Logstash, with one Logstash doing all the aggregations and one (or more) LS doing the rest of the treatment.